# Domain names mapping in phonegap

Tags: cordova, dns

I have API which my phonegap app should communicate with on somehost.com. However for debuging I want to use my my local API service. How can I configure phonegap (or emulator) to redirect all requests sent to somehost.com to my local IP:port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any ways to do it except editing `hosts` file on my avd. Fortunately to do it I do not need root assess to emulated device.

short guide:

- run device emulator with `emulator -avd someDevice -partition-size 128`

  **NOTE: `-partition-size` parameter is necessary to write hosts file at last step**
- remount device `adb remount`
- pull `hosts` file to home OS `adb pull /system/etc/hosts ~/development/`
- edit just pulled `hosts` file with your favorite text editor
- push edited `hosts` file back to emulated device `adb push ~/development/hosts /system/etc`

Answer (score 0):

I do this by assigning my API URL to a variable and then in all of my API calls I reference the variable. That way, when I am testing I set the one variable to my test URL and then when I send it live I set it back to the public URL.

Example for testing:

```
var api_url = '111.111.111.111:8888';
//var api_url = 'http://my.domain.com';

$.get(api_url + '/someEndpoint');
```

Comment: This is obvious solution, but I hope to find way how to do it with configuration instead changing all urls in code.

Comment: In that case, you will need to root the device/emulator and edit `/etc/hosts` adding an entry such as `111.111.111.111:8888 my.domain.com` and then restarting the device/emulator. This will cause all traffic to your domain to route to the local address.